# Can someone explain this Python code to me?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def spin_words(sentence):
    # Your code goes here
    return " ".join([x[::-1] if len(x) >= 5 else x for x in sentence.split(" ")])
```

I don't understand this one.

Comment: this basically reverses the sentence when the number of words is greater than equal to 5. else it returns the same string.

Comment: It splits the sentence into a list of words, and inverts the words of 5 characters or more, then joins the list to a string again.

Comment: Note that the outer square brackets `[]` are not only unnecessary, but result in the needless creation of a temporary list.  Just delete them, leaving the comprehension as a generator.  The code will produce the same result.

Comment: This is the problem with having other people do your Codewars homework for you -- you're not going to actually learn to code the same way you would by writing your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sentence.split(" ")` gets all the words in the `sentence` input parameter by separating when it finds a whitespace.

`for x in sentence.split(" ")` applies the loop to each word resulting from the previous statement

`x[::-1] if len(x) >= 5 else x`   reverses the word if its length is greater than 5

`return " ".join` returns the result of the previous statement, joining the words with whitespaces